# How do you target the Jquery .load function inside a dynamically generated div

Tags: php, jquery, dom, load, onchange

short:
How do you use the Jquery .load function inside a dynamically generated div, but target a non clicked ID.

The idea is that I have a button that adds new divs every time clicked with "name+(sequential id") using the "$().append()" feature of jquery. Once the Div is added to the page a "$().load()" fills the div with two select boxes and another div.

Once loaded the user is able to use the first select box to select a value.

When value is selected the "$().on('click'" feature in Jquery checks too see if it was first option box is clicked and changed.

At this point after the first option box is selected and changed a "().load()" is used to update "#ajax-load-1" div surrounding the second option box. This is where i cannot get the ".load" to see the ID of the div.

I have done many a search and come up empty handed, a lot of tutorials on how to use .on("click" to get a ID of an element that was dynamically generated but not one that wasn't clicked.

Here is a simplified example of the code described above.

Html:

```
<!-- |This box has been dynamically generated and named through a Jquery .load() | -->

<div id="dynamic-box-1">

<select id="select-1">

    <option>1</option>

    <option>2</option>

</select>

<!-- | div to be .load()'ed after an option is selected in #select-1 |-->
<div id="ajax-load-1">

    <select id="ajax-select-1">

        <option>1</option>

        <option>2</option>

    </select>

</div>

</div>

<!-- | End of dynamic box | -->
```

Jquery

```
$("#select-1").on("click", function(){

$("#select-1").change(function(){

       $("#ajax-load-1").load("../php/ajax-load-1.php");

});

});
```

Comment: Why do you have `change` event nested inside `click` event

Comment: @Sushanth because he's confused about how event delegation works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try using event delegation**

Replace

```
$("#select-1").change(function(){
```

with

```
$(document).on('change', '#select-1', function(){
```

And remove the click event encasing it.

If the `HTML` you have provided is the one you expect to see in the application. then you can get the `id` of the div with something like this

```
 $(document).on('change', '#select-1', function(){
     var divId = $(this).next('div').attr('id');
     $("#" + divId ).load("../php/" + divId + '"php");
 });
```

Comment: I think that his current application design is to try and create new elements leveraging an iterator, so `#select-1` should be `[id^=select]`, and inside his function, he should use `var theID = $(this).prop('id').split('-')[1]` to get the `int value`. Then he can use that for his selector when targetting his other elements, `"ajax-load-"+theID` and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice, ill implement these changes and get back with my results!

Comment: Maid the adjustments recommended and everything works perfectly thank you for your answer !